# Memory and CPU efficiency in If statements

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm discussing with some colleagues about the efficiency of If statements and which is the best in cost of memory and CPU use, at this stage, doesn't matter the language used.

The two conditionals is the following:

```
If value is present then
  skip

If value = "1234" then
  execute
```

So, the first controlls if the value is null, in that case exit (skip) the routine, the second statement compare the variable to a specific value.
What I'm thinking is that the first uses more CPU and the second more Ram, what do you think about it?

Do I have to use both so that if the value is null the second statement is skipped? Or is better to use only the second who compare two values?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate why second uses more ram? "1234" will be placed in memory only once as a const value. Code which do comparison is also compiled and generated only once. In fact second If might be more CPU consuming by comparing strings, but I don't think you can do much with this. So not really sure how you get to your conclusions. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, 1234 is just an example, the statement is executed millions of time during the day, "value" is always different and "1234" can be 4 or more value to compare.
I'm thinking if leave only the second, or add also the first statement so if the "value" is null, the second will be skipped. So the question is, which is better from "compare if null" and "compare between two numbers"?

Comment: so basically you want ```if value != null && value == "1234" {...} ```. But this has nothing to do with memory consumption.